# Should I add both JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME in environmental variable, PATH?

Tags: java, tomcat8

I ran into this error while setting up my Tomcat and Java environmental path:

> Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environmental variables is
>   defined.  At least one of the 2 environmental variables is needed to
>   run this program.

In the user variables: I created **JAVA_HOME** variables and add ***C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25*** to its path. and then did an edit of system variable **PATH**, added ***C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25;*** to the beginning of the its path.
I also created **JRE_HOME** in user variable and added ***C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25*** to its path.

Is it necessary to create JRE_HOME and should I add the JRE path to the system variable also?

Comment: No it is not nessary to add JRE_HOME. Might be Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120279/difference-between-java-home-and-jre-home

Comment: side note: You typically add "%JAVA_HOME%/bin" to the path.  In your case, there is no reason to add java paths to "path" var.

Comment: Kind of similar question is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551668/how-do-i-set-the-default-java-installation-runtime-windows/48690194#48690194

Answer (score 17):

This answer explains all the steps **with screenshots and examples**

Better Use the 8.3 directory-format. In fact No spaces, ever.
[image: 8.3 naming]

1. **`JAVA_HOME`** - your ***JDK*** folder
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45` == `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_4`
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71` == `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_7`
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25` == `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_2`
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.9.0` == `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK19~1.0`
2. **`JRE_HOME`**
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6` == `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre6`
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7` == `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre7`
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25` == `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JRE18~1.0_2`
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.9.0` == `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JRE19~1.0`
3. **Addition to `PATH` - best practice!**

   - USE <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
   - Enter `C:\Windows\system32\systempropertiesadvanced.exe`
   - Add `;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;` to the end of `PATH`
     (System Variables not User Variables).
     [image]
   - Click OK, explore to `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\` and rename `javapath` folder (from `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\`) to `javapath_old`.
   - Create new folder named `javapath`.
   - Start CMD and browse into (the now empty) `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\`.
   - Run to create symbolic links:

     1. `ln -s "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" java.exe`
     2. `ln -s "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" javaw.exe`
     3. `ln -s "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaws.exe" javaws.exe`
        [image]
   - Done with `PATH` and `*_HOME`, now let's continue with the Windows Registry.
4. Open up you preferred registry editor ([Registry Workshop](http://www.torchsoft.com/en/download.html) is the best), browse `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit` notice all installed versions are shown as keys, double click `CurrentVersion` (REG_SZ value) and modify its data to your preferred SDK version, mine is 1.7 (For [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements))
   [image: Registry edit]
5. Do the same for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` (with `CurrentVersion`)
   [image: Registry edit]
6. Close down java-based programs such as eclipse or [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/),

   - Open up task-manager- processes tab,
   - Look for `explorer.exe`, `cmd.exe` and `java(*something*).exe` programs,
   - Right-click eache and click *End Task* (not "End Process-Tree"!)
   - Click `File`➩`New Task`➩enter `explorer.exe`
     .

The changes you've done above were applied successfully
No need to reboot, no need to log-off/on again.

Comment: very good explanation that give interesting shortcuts ( WINDOWS+R, C:\Windows\system32\systempropertiesadvanced.exe...)

Comment: On my Win7 x64 I had no need to touch the registry. But I had to erase the C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\ from the PATH variable and cut/paste the symlinks to somewhere else.

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheBlanchard or just press the windows key and type "env" ;) (start menu finds everything easy)

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

**For Java**,

In the User variables, add `PATH` value is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;`

**For Tomcat**

In the System variables, add `JAVA_HOME` value is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`

Now classpath has been set to your machine. You can access java from anywhere in your machine.

After Done this, Go to `Command Prompt` and go to **ApacheTomcat*x.x** and move to `bin` folder,,

**Start the Server**

```
startup.bat
```

For check Tomcat running status, Go to your browser, and **Paste the URL,**

http://localhost:8080/

**Stop the Server**

```
shutdown.bat
```

Comment: I like this simple answer. Also refer to the [answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17044342/744133).

Comment: @JoD. Thank you for comment. Will try to give best answer to SO always.

Answer (score 2):

You really do not need to add `JRE_HOME` to the system variables. Tomcat looks for `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME` to get itself start. This is because tomcat require some java library to get itself started. Tomcat will provide additional debugging functionality if Jdk is provided instead of Jre. Additional details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120279/difference-between-java-home-and-jre-home)

Adding `{JAVA_HOME_DIR}/bin` to your path would enable to access java from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

After modifying system variables , it is important to **open new console window**