# Setting JAVA_HOME on centos for root and normal user --> checking java -version

Tags: centos, java-home

actually i im learning Linux (CentOs 7). I installed Java on root `(usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java)`.

Now i have one question. if i type "java-version" i get

```
[mibe@localhost ~]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

I thought that java only works if i set the `JAVA_HOME`  PATH in  `/etc/profile`. Why do i get a result for this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you installed java in `/usr/lib`, this folder is in system environment. When you type `java -version`, the system can find the command `java`.
But if you install java in other folder not in system environment, you must set the `JAVA_HOME` PATH in  `/etc/profile` to tell the system how to find the `java` command, and there are other important reasons why to set the `JAVA_HOME` not just for this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27996647/11559693